# how do i create a auto adaptive form

Tags: html, forms, dynamic

I want to create a dynamic form on my website.

On my site a have several forms that are subject specific but i also have a contact us form with a subject dropdown from which they can choose any of the subjects that the subject specific forms cover.

now if they select website design enquiry i need to ask them for their website address whereas website address isn't relevant to all of the other enquiry subjects, if they ask about website hosting i again need their website address but also need their preference of hosting package.

if they ask about mobile app development i don't need the website or hosting package fields but need 4 checkboxes to appear to allow them to tick the ones relating to the platforms for which the mobile app is to be developed for.

so it needs to be auto adaptive to the type of enquiry selected.

how can i acheive this?

Comment: You can add/remove/change elements on the page dynamically using [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/JavaScript_Overview).

Comment: are you happy to use javascript or jQuery? what are you expecting from the answer, an example code or the language to choose to achieve this, or maybe example websites providing implementations...?

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery, to achieve that.

you need to add jQuery change listener on the dropdown select. then you add form elements to a container accroding to selected value.

here is a small example

```
$( ".select" ).change(function() {
    var value = this.val();
    if(value == "webDesign")
    {
        $("#fieldsContainer").append('<input name="webUrl" class="inputField"/>');
    }
});
```

you can also change action url accroding to select Value so it will be more easy to handle different forms

```
if(value == "webDesign")
{
     $("form#myForm").attr('action','process.php?type=webdesign');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite vague, but the answer to it is that there are many ways to achieve it. One of the most commonly used ways is to use javascript (or some library like jQuery using js).

I have put together a basic function for you that will showcase how it's done in pure js:

#### HTML:

```html
Services: <select id="service">
    <option value="stuff">stuff</option>
    <option value="webdesign">webdesign</option>
</select><br />
<span id="webname">Website: <input type="text" /></span>
```

#### JS:

```js
document.getElementById("service").onchange = function () {
    if (document.getElementById("service").options[document.getElementById("service").selectedIndex].value == "webdesign")
        document.getElementById("webname").style.display = "none";
    else
        document.getElementById("webname").style.display = "block";
}
```

Here is the demo page of the above code: **http://jsfiddle.net/w3pGr/**

Comment: i tried to do this but it isnt working so here is my code

###JS:

<!-- language: lang-js -->
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("Subject").onchange = function () {
    if (document.getElementById("Subject").options[document.getElementById("Subject").selectedIndex].value == "Mobile App Development Enquiry")
        document.getElementById("maplatform").style.display = "none";
    else
        document.getElementById("maplatform").style.display = "block";
}
</script>

for html code go to http://www.admiralsystems.co.uk/Contact%20Us.html and view source

Comment: "isn't working" is no definition of an error or anything really... what is not working / what did you expect to happen? also, do not include code in comment, it's not the place for it; what do you want me to do with it?

Comment: okay it wasnt working at that point because i put the script in the head area i now have the script in the body and it kind of works but what i now need is the default value of the select field is "General Enquiry" so these fields need to be hidden on load but appear when the select box changes to the correct value. but also i am using tables in this case the header is on one tr and the field on the next and both have to disappear until the correct dropdown option is selected.

Comment: one of the reasons we advised against a general questions like yours is to stop endless comments like these... this is (like it or not) not a tutorial page, but a questions and answers page where you'll get help for specific questions... so either ask another question or search a little more...

Comment: i appreciate what your saying but if you can't help me directly you could at least point me to a page or specific individual who i can communicate with privately to get this resolved. i don't know where to look for the answers you do which i why i keep posting this question over and over.

Comment: google is your good friend, that's how I learned, never talked to anyone... in this business you won't get far without doing your homework or you'll depend on others forever... also posting the same question over and over again will, sooner or later, just get your account deleted over and over again... email me through my blog (you'll find it on my profile)...